# Link style is overwritten by magento default link style

Tags: css, magento

I want to add some custom links all with different colors. But whenever I edit them, the magento default css overwrites that style. I can't just edit the magento default css because I only want those particular links to be those colors, not the whole website.

I tried using this code:

```
.blue-stores, .blue-stores:link, .blue-stores:visited, 
.blue-stores:active, .blue-stores:focus, .blue-stores:hover {
        color: #2da48f;
        font-size: 14px;
}
```

But it still uses the default style.

Anyone know how to style these links without changing all of them?

Comment: I think that [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) should help you in understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you post the magento style for a link so we know what you're trying to override?  In my experience, when CSS like this doesn't override another CSS rule, your CSS selector isn't specific enough.  It may be as simple as changing to `a.blue-stores, a.blue-stores:link, etc...` but I'd need to see the magento style because I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by making my css more specific.

For example I used this code:

```
.blue-stores a{
 /* code */
}
```

Which worked for me.